# Turn ON speaker in incoming call Android

Tags: java, android, audio, speaker

I would like to turn on the speaker and set it to maximum volume.
In my PhoneStateListener I'm intercepting the incoming call, and it works fine for any incoming/outgoing call.

The thing is that I want to turn on this feature only for two specific incoming numbers.

This is my code:

```
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        if (incomingNumber.equals( strRegisterNumber1) || incomingNumber.equals( strRegisterNumber2))
        {
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) contextMember.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);

        }
        break;
```

Without the if statement it works fine but int his case the speaker stays off.

Please advise what I'm doing wrong or how to achieve my goal?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, your speaker enable / set volume code is working - it's the string comparisons that always return false? Have you tried logging all three strings to see what they contain?

Comment: Yes. Two strings. That's the strange thing. They contain the incoming number exactly as I wanted. I don't understand were's the problem.

Comment: I use the same if statement later and it returns true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instaed of

```
incomingNumber.equals( strRegisterNumber1) || incomingNumber.equals( strRegisterNumber2)
```

use

```
incomingNumber.contains( strRegisterNumber1) || incomingNumber.contains( strRegisterNumber2)
```

Because the incoming number might have `+` with country code or `00` with country code. So you just have to check if the incoming call's number contains the required number.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Tried it. No change. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you checked/printed/logged the values of `incomingNumber`, `strRegisterNumber1` and `strRegisterNumber2` before the `if` statement.