# How to turn on speaker for incoming call programmatically in Android L?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-audiomanager

I want to accept an incoming call using answering phone's GUI (Phone's GUI) of my phone in Android 5.0. I found a way that needs to make an activity which use to send some action to open the Phone's GUI. I was successful to turn on the Phone's GUI for an incoming call. The issue is how can I turn on the speaker for the Phone's GUI. I tried the code but it does not turn on. Could you help me to solve that issue in Android L

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
if (!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn())
     audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Besides, do we have more shoter way to open accept a incoming call using answering phone's intent. My way is so long because it use an Activity.

This is my full class code

```
public class AcceptCallActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String MANUFACTURER_HTC = "HTC";
    private KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private CallStateReceiver callStateReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerCallStateReceiver();
        updateWindowFlags();
        acceptCall();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (callStateReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(callStateReceiver);
            callStateReceiver = null;
        }
    }

    private void registerCallStateReceiver() {
        callStateReceiver = new CallStateReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(callStateReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    private void updateWindowFlags() {
        if (keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
            getWindow().addFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        }
    }

    private void acceptCall() {

        // for HTC devices we need to broadcast a connected headset
        boolean broadcastConnected = MANUFACTURER_HTC.equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MANUFACTURER)
                && !audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn();

        if (broadcastConnected) {
            broadcastHeadsetConnected(false);
        }

        try {
            try {
                Log.d("AnswerCall","execute input keycode headset hook");
                //Turn on speaker
                audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                if (!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn())
                    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
                        Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Runtime.exec(String) had an I/O problem, try to fall back
                Log.d("AnswerCall","send keycode headset hook intents");
                String enforcedPerm = "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED";
                Intent btnDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                Intent btnUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

                sendOrderedBroadcast(btnDown, enforcedPerm);
                sendOrderedBroadcast(btnUp, enforcedPerm);
            }
        } finally {
            if (broadcastConnected) {
                broadcastHeadsetConnected(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void broadcastHeadsetConnected(boolean connected) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
        i.putExtra("state", connected ? 1 : 0);
        i.putExtra("name", "mysms");
        try {
            sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }


    private class CallStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16188831/2900127

Comment: I tried that link before but it does not work for my phone

Comment: If you are using API level >= 23 then check runtime permission also and if possible then check logcat you may receive any kind of error or warning then put it here

Comment: @Vickyexpert: Sorry for my late reply. I tried to show log or warning but it has not warning. I am using Android level 21. I cannot turn on speak of the answer phone GUI

Comment: I'm not sure, if it's can be done using SDK, but you can do it with Xposed module

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. I put above code run inside a thread. It worked well. This is my code. Hope it can help someone

```
            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while(true) {
                            sleep(1000);
                            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                            if (!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn())
                                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            thread.start();
```

Comment: Hi  @jame 
I am trying to accomplish similar thing I have few phones with no ringer working I am trying to develop an APP that enable loud speaker when I receive call plus when I bring it near my earn the sensor turns of the display and the speaker switch of to headphone. any solution?

Comment: Why the need of the thread? Why not run on the UI thread and that's it? Worked for me...

Comment: Does it work in android 10 for you? for me it did not working. Please advice.

Comment: This is nonsense... Why do we need to do this. The hell??? I was thinking some method would just toggle the Speaker Mode switch on the Phone app or something! At least works haha. Thank you!
EDIT: Actually there's no need for the while loop. Just put it inside a thread and that's it. Maybe it just can't run on the main thread or something. Interesting. Finally working...

Answer (score -1):

I came across this solution. hope it helps you.

```
final static int FOR_MEDIA = 1;

final static int FORCE_NONE = 0;

final static int FORCE_SPEAKER = 1;

Class audioSystemClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");

Method setForceUse = audioSystemClass.getMethod("setForceUse", int.class, int.class);

setForceUse.invoke(null, FOR_MEDIA, FORCE_SPEAKER);
```